# NSFetchedResultsController Freezing UI

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am having a problem using NSFetchedResultsController where I cant stop it from freezing the UI. The initial fetch happens quickly but when I fire any fault it causes freezing when scrolling the table view. I am only using 8 elements for testing and am using StackMob for my back-end

Here is where I declare the NSFetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    } 
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" 
                                   inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
   [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"createddate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And here is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor* backgroundImage = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TAN]];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:backgroundImage];
    [[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    _managedObjectContext =  [[self.appDelegate coreDataStore] contextForCurrentThread];

    NSError *error;     
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();  // Fail
    }
}
```

and here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CCCell";
    CCCell *cell = (CCCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setDelegate:self];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    Post* post = (Post*)[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //
    //IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IT LOCKS THE UI
    //
    //NSLog(@"%@", [post valueForKey:@"price"]);
    return cell;
}
```

Where if I uncomment the line specified it causes very slow scrolling

I have tried to surround the call with a call like this

```
dispatch_queue_t coreDataThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.YourApp.YourThreadName", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(coreDataThread, ^{
    Post* post = (Post*)[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", [post valueForKey:@"price"]);
});
```

But then it takes a very long time 20 sec or so

Answer (score 1):

Set a `fetchBatchSize` on your fetch request equal to about twice the number of rows your table will have onscreen. That will save having to load the entire dataset. Also see `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation on `cacheName`.

Your `[[self.appDelegate coreDataStore] contextForCurrentThread]` looks suspicious, by the way. All of this UI code will be executed on the main thread, so asking another object to generate per-thread MOC's is almost certainly not necessary.

Your GCD code is incorrect because you now have both the main UI thread and your GCD `coreDataThread` talking to the same `NSFetchedResultsController`, thus two threads talking to the same MOC.

It's worth turning on SQL logging if you're ever baffled by Core Data performance.

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

as a command-line argument, enabled through the Scheme Editor.